# Git submodule builds in Jenkins, show changes from submodules since last build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, git-submodules

I have a git module which contains several submodules. I am using jenkins to build. I am using the advanced settings enabled

- `Recursively update submodules`
- `Update tracking submodules to tip of branch`
- `Use credentials from default remote of parent repository`

This creates a nice build on master and moves all the submodules to the tip of their master branch unfortunately when Jenkins  it will only show commits on the module and not any of the submodules. How do I configure it to show all the commits across all the submodules?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported AFAIK. We have created a patch to support it.
Look here https://github.com/eprstov/git-plugin and
https://github.com/eprstov/git-client-plugin for *sbm branches.